# How to disable some nav Items on dashboard depends on role with angular 5?

Tags: angular

in my app i have two kinds of users , an admin and a consumer , they both use the same dashboard component , some of the nav Items are for admin and the oahers are for consumer,
in my case i have "All consumers" item is for the admin and the rest for consumers,

[image]

This i how i add an item to the dashboard , just by adding an object with name and URL ..

[image]

I already used "canActivate" with a guard in routes that returns False but it just make it inaccessible , but i want to hide it , what I should do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the userRole in localStorage, and use ngIf else conditions to show/ hide nav items by checking the userRole.

example :

```
<li *ngIf="userRole === 'Consumer'; else adminData">
</li>
<ng-template #adminData>
    ** whatever you want to show if the userRole is admin **
 </ng-template>
```

Comment: I add an item to the dashboard , just by adding an object with name and URL in _nav.ts not by <li>

Answer (score 0):

In your _nav.ts file, you can have an extra attribute:

```
{ 
  name: 'All consumers',
  url: '/dash/admin/consumers',
  icon: 'icon-people',
  adminOnly: true
}
```

In the component you can get those for adminOnly

```
if (userRole === 'admin') {
   navItems = navItems.filter(item => item.adminOnly);
}
```

Then in your template you can loop normally in the navItems.